# Why does looping over a vector of POSIXct-times change the type in R?

Tags: r, posixct

I am using R on a regular basis and I have stumbled above something weird:

```
Sys.time() |> class()
times <- Sys.time()+1:3
print(times)
for (tme in times) {
  print(tme)
}
tme %in% times
```

This gives the output:

```
> Sys.time() |> class()
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> times <- Sys.time()+1:3
> print(times)
[1] "2024-01-18 10:00:28 CET" "2024-01-18 10:00:29 CET" "2024-01-18 10:00:30 CET"
> for (tme in times) {
+   print(tme)
+ }
[1] 1705568429
[1] 1705568430
[1] 1705568431
> tme %in% times
[1] FALSE
```

How is such a behaviour justifiable? I find the last line especially hard to justify (`tme %in% times == FALSE`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reason behind

In `for` loop, the expression `times` will be coerced to a `vector` (when you see the help document by typing `` ?`for` ``

> An expression evaluating to a vector (including a list and an
> expression) or to a pairlist or NULL. A factor value will be coerced
> to a character vector. This can be a long vector.

However, in `vector`, no attribute will be retained (when typing `?vector` and see the description)

> vector produces a ‘simple’ vector of the given length and mode, where
> a ‘simple’ vector has no attribute, i.e., fulfills
> is.null(attributes(.)).

## Workaround

To keep all the attributes, you can convert the values in `times` into a list, for example, you can use `as.list(times)` in `for` loop like below

```
> for (time in as.list(times)) {
+     print(time)
+ }
[1] "2024-01-18 10:13:39 CET"
[1] "2024-01-18 10:13:40 CET"
[1] "2024-01-18 10:13:41 CET"
```

or you can use `sapply` like below

```
> invisible(sapply(times, print))
[1] "2024-01-18 10:13:39 CET"
[1] "2024-01-18 10:13:40 CET"
[1] "2024-01-18 10:13:41 CET"
```

Comment: @Roland yes, I was going to point out that attributes (including classes) are dropped from the iterator. This seems to happen in the underlying C code in `do_for` ([here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/eval.c#L1577) ). Otherwise, it seems the attributes would have to be copied for every iteration. This is the "why" that was asked in the question.

Comment: @AllanCameron yes, the clues can be found in the documents about `for` and `vector`, see my update.

Comment: So unlike for types like character, integer or numeric, the posixct type is only stored as an attribute which is dropped in the for loop iteration? And the underlying data type of a posixct is numeric?

Comment: @Noskario yes, you are right